# transmission error when sending more than 1024 bytes through a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a file through socket.

When I set len of [send()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/2020?topic=apis-send-send-data-connected-socket) to be more than 1024, there're chances of receiving wrong data from send().

If I set len to be 1024, it always works fine.

Is it because the MTU limit of 1500 bytes? If so, why [The maximum send buffer size is 1,048,576 bytes?](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/2020?topic=apis-send-send-data-connected-socket)

Core parts of the code:

```
\\server.cpp
fstream in(cmds[1], ios::in | ios::binary);

size_t chunk, rest;
in.seekg(0, ios::end);
chunk = in.tellg() / MAXTEXT;
rest  = in.tellg() % MAXTEXT;
in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

connfd.send(&chunk, sizeof(size_t));
connfd.send(&rest, sizeof(size_t));
perror("Error: ");

for (size_t i = 0; i < chunk; ++i) {
    in.read(buf, MAXTEXT);
    connfd.send(buf, MAXTEXT);
}
in.read(buf, rest);
connfd.send(buf, rest);

in.close();
cout << "File upload done" << endl;
```

```
\\client.cpp
fstream out(cmds[2], ios::out | ios::binary);

size_t chunk, rest;
connfd.recv(&chunk, sizeof(size_t));
connfd.recv(&rest, sizeof(size_t));
perror("Error: ");
            
auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (size_t i = 0; i < chunk; ++i) {
    connfd.recv(buf, MAXTEXT);
    out.write(buf, MAXTEXT);
//  show_process_bar((double)(i+1)/(double)chunk);
}
connfd.recv(buf, rest);
out.write(buf, rest);

auto endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto totalTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();

out.close();

cout << "File download done, Total time: "
     << totalTime
     << "ms, Average speed: "
     << chunk * MAXTEXT / 1024 / 1024 * 1000 / totalTime
     << " MiB/s" << endl;
```

when type "get /mnt/c/Users/yieatn/Documents/test.pdf /home/yieatn/test.pdf"

It tends to work fine in the first time, but then i found **chunk** and **rest** are messed up

I'm guessing some data weren't wroten into buf, which causes unexpected data wroted into **chunk** and **rest**

```
version:
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
```

the complete code can be found here [code](https://github.com/yieatn/ftp)

Comment: A TCP/IP socket at the application layer is a data-stream.  There are __no__ packets at the application layer.  Each `send` may be merged with subsequent sends or arbitrarily split etc before being transmitted over the network.  If you need an application messaging protocol then you need to invent a message format and parse the data-stream in the application (length prefixed messaging is very simple to implement). The individual messages may be split and/or merged across each `recv` call.

Comment: There is no 'transmission error' here. The actual problem here is not errors on sending, it is that you are completely ignoring the value returned by `read()`. It is impossible to write correct I/O code, let alone networking code, while doing that.

Comment: The return values of both send() and recv() should always be checked, since both calls return the number of bytes they actually sent/received, which may be less than the number of bytes you requested them to send/receive, in which case you’ll need to handle that shortfall gracefully.